# How to make combobox in wicket?

Tags: combobox, wicket

Can someone give me a point, how to make combobox in wicket. It should be editable field with options loading by ajax. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this example should be right for what you need:

http://examples8x.wicket.apache.org/ajax/autocomplete

In addition, you can take a look at this WicketStuff project that integrates [Select2](https://select2.org/) framework with Wicket:

https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/select2-parent

Comment: Unfortunately Autocomplete can choose invalid value and select 2 doesnt support autocomplete as well :-(.